# iOS SFSafariViewController load a blank page without navigationBar or toolBar

Tags: ios, safari

in my project, I used SafariVC instead of wkwebview, then, I meet the problem that I present a SafariVC loading URL in some device like iphone6s(iOS10.3.2) normally, but **in iphone6(iOS9.3) the SafariVC show a blank page without NavigationBar or ToolBar**, it's very strange, and I try lots of ways but don't work. it's look like a bug in Safari by Apple themselves。

code:

```
SFSafariViewController *safariVC = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
[self presentViewController:safariVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

help~

Answer (score 0):

Just tested the code you posted. Works good on iPhone 4s with 9.3.
Simple app with one button, when you press it, this code runs:

```
- (IBAction)onSafari:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sme.sk"];
    SFSafariViewController *safariVC = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [self presentViewController:safariVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You are probably doing also something else that is not written here.

Comment: the code is ok I believe, but I get lots of user's feedback that safari is blank, and the safariVC can't pop, I think if the bug of safari to handle the url

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue yourself? Because I can't reproduce it from info you posted here.

Comment: `- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction
decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler` in this method, I intercept the url and open safariVC by the url.